# Relationship between the standard basis vectors, and the vector space and a subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra

Would it be true to say that, although a vector space of R$^n$ can always be written in terms of the standard basis vectors (e$_1$, e$_2$, ... , e$_n$), a subspace does not necessarily have to contain any of the standard basis vectors?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is true. Consider in $\mathbb{R}^3$ a plane passing through the origin that does not contain any of the coordinate axis. It is a subspace of dimension $2$.

Comment: Thank you again Emilio. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. Do you consider that  $a(e_1+e_2), a\in \mathbb {R}$ to be written thanks to the standard basis ? If yes, then every subspace can be written in the standard basis. Take one of its basis and write it in the standard basis.

If you consider this is not "written with the standard basis ", then no, some subspaces are not generated only by a subset of the standard basis

Comment: I'm referring to whether or not the subspace contains the standard basis.